# Record List Header Properties Not Working In Mobile View

Tags: customer-community, responsive-design, digital-experience

**tl;dr** - How can get Header Property Configurations to persist in mobile view of a Customer Community/Experience?

**Problem**

I need buttons/actions to be hidden on a Record List component on a Customer Community/Experience page. When viewing from a desktop, I am able to do this without issue (see image 1 and 2).

---

**Image 1:** "Show Actions" is unchecked

[image]

---

**Image 2:** Actions do not appear in record list, as desired.

[image]

---

However, when I change the view to mobile, the hidden actions reappear (see image 3)

---

**Image 3:** The action button "New" has reappeared, despite no change to the Header Properties of the Record List component.
[image]

---

After further investigation in the experience Builder, it appears that no changes to the Header Properties are taking effect while the component is viewed from a mobile perspective (I've tried several). Once the view returns to desktop, the configured Header Properties display as desired.

I haven't found anything [in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_record_list_view.htm&type=0) to indicate that this is standard functionality for Communities/Experiences, nor have I had any luck finding this issue posted by others online.

**Question**

How can I make changes to the Record List component's Header Properties persist in mobile view?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have been able to determine, this is a limitation of the standard Record List component. While it isn't a direct solution to my original question, I resolved my issue by creating a custom aura component. This new component allows for more fine-tuned control of what an experience/community user sees, and maintains those configurations across desktop and mobile devices.

This custom component has some visual and functional differences from the standard Record List component, but I have included a link to the Github repository [here](https://github.com/Jwok90/UsefulSalesforceTidbits/tree/main/Bits/Aura/customRecordListView) in case anyone finds it helpful.